# Opening all links from iPhone gmail app opens my app

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.forms

We have the odd situation where the iPhone app we've developed in Xamarin Forms is somehow intercepting all links in the Gmail app's emails, not just the links we intend our app to process. The user taps any link, and Gmail opens the link directly in our app instead of opening it in chrome or safari.
The only way to prevent this behavior is to go into Gmail settings and set Safari as the default browser.

Is this something that could be caused by an incorrect apple-app-site-association file?

This is the association file we are using for a domain where we process all paths in that domain. Other association files on other domains are more specific (specifying subpaths).

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "xxx.yyy",
                "paths": [ "/", "" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You might wanna remove your appID if it is the one that you have in the application for security purpose!

Comment: Thanks. I came to that realisation. Logged in and saw your post. 

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution to the problem. A change had been made to the info.plist file in the iOS project, which caused our app to process Google Chrome links from Gmail. The **googlechromes** entry was the cause.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>googlechromes</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```